# cannot find -lcurl while compiling program with buildroot-gcc463 toolchain

Tags: libcurl

I am using Very simple HTTP GET C code using libcurl.

When I compile the code using gcc, it compiles and runs successfully. Now I want to compile the same code using buildroot-gcc463 toolchain cross compiler, it given me error cannot find -lcurl

```
anand@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ gcc simple.c -o simple -lcurl
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
anand@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ ./simple
<!doctype html>
<html>
….. // page contents here
</head>
</html>
----------------------------------------------------------------------------        
anand@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ /opt/buildroot-gcc463/usr/bin/mipsel-linux-gcc     
simple.c -o simple -lcurl
/opt/buildroot-gcc463/usr/lib/gcc/mipsel-buildroot-linux-uclibc/4.6.3/../../../../mipsel-buildroot-linux-uclibc/bin/ld: cannot find -lcurl collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I tried several different ways to compile it such as using -L or --sysroot option, but same error. Please help.

Comment: And you have libcurl installed in a path that your cross-compiler searches by default? If not, in which path and how did you use `-L` ?